# Finding data using a related field in CakePHP 2.4

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm trying to get a list of users in my CakePHP 2.4 app who have contributed posts to a particular project (think 'category'). My data relates as following:

**Project** hasMany **Post**

**User** hasMany **Post**

**Post** belongsTo **Project** and **User**.

I'm trying to do a find in my Projects `view` method to get a list of contributors:

```
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->loadModel('Post');
    $this->set('contributors', $this->Project->Post->User->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('Post.project_id' => $id)
    )));
```

Ideally, this should give me a list of users who have created Posts with a `project_id` equal to $id. However, I get an error: `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Post.project_id' in 'where clause'`.

Clearly, the ORM isn't making sense of my code: It doesn't know what the hell I mean by `project_id`. Is it possible to get a list of users by searching for a field in a related model? Or is this beyond the capability of the CakePHP object system?

This is an approximation of what I'm trying to do, in SQL. I still don't want to go bare SQL because all sources tell me it's a rotten idea. **How can I build a similar query in a Cake find?**

```
SELECT 
    users.* 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            posts
        WHERE 
            users.id = posts.user_id 
            AND 
            posts.project_id = " . $id . "
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Cake that does the trick: This code sucessfully lists all `Users` who have created `Posts` that have the `project_id` I'm looking for.

```
$contributors = array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'posts',
                'alias' => 'Post',
                'type' => 'inner',

                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.id = Post.user_id',
                    'Post.project_id' => $id,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'fields' => array('User.*'),
        'group' => array('User.id'),
        'contain' => array()
    );

    $this->set('contributors', $this->User->find('all', $contributors));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$user=$this->Post->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Post.project_id' => $id)));

$this->set('contributors', 'user');
```

Then you can use `debug($user); exit;` to view the result you will receive

Comment: That gives a list of posts that belong to that project. I'm trying to make a list of users who have created posts that belong to the project.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question. Can you please update or delete it?

Comment: Please edit your answer according to what the OP is asking for